# C# Blazor CascadingParameter - Atualização de Componentes

Tags: blazor

Boa tarde,

Estou iniciando no blazor c#
Estou tentando fazer um componente de contextMenu que deveria ficar instanciado no meu MainLayout, onde todos os filhos que forem renderizados no @body do MainLayout tenham acesso a esse contextMenu e possam passar um renderFragment como conteúdo desse menu.

O código que fiz até agora foi:

MainLayout:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="sidebar" @onclick="sideBar_Click">
    <NavMenu />
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="content px-4">
        <CascadingValue Value="contextMenu">
            @Body
        </CascadingValue>
    </div>
</div>


@code {
    ContextMenu contextMenu { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (contextMenu == null)
            contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private void sideBar_Click()
    {
        contextMenu.Teste();
    }
}
```

Meu componente ContextMenu:

```
<div style="background-color:cornflowerblue;">
    <div>
        @Conteudo
        <span>Conteudo dinamico: @dinamico</span>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment Conteudo { get; set; }
    private string dinamico = "";

    public void Teste()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Teste executado");
        dinamico = "texto dinamico";
        Console.WriteLine(dinamico);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Meu Index, que está sendo renderizado no BodY:

```
@page "/"

<ContextMenu @ref="contextMenu">
    <Conteudo>
        <span>Teste</span>
    </Conteudo>
</ContextMenu>

@code{
    [CascadingParameter] ContextMenu contextMenu { get; set; }
}
```

Ou seja, no final de tudo eu quero que ao clicar na div sideBard, seja disparado um evento no meu ContexMenu que tem seu conteudo definido em cada componente filho , e o componente contextMenu seja atualizado.

Do jeito que estou fazendo apresenta o seguinte erro no console do navegador, quando clico na sidebard:

**Unhandled exception rendering component: The render handle is not yet assigned.**

Alguém sabe se estou fazendo de maneira correta essa atualização de componentes? Procurei bastante mas não achei nada misto de parâmetros de cascata com renderfragments.

Se possível alguém ajudar a solucionar o problema ae ou mostrar uma outra solução viável para o problema eu agradeço,